# Local JacORB call: org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST

Tags: java, jboss5.x, corba, jacorb

We use JacORB 2.3.0 with Java 6 and JBoss 5.1.0 in a legacy project. The CORBA infrastructure and the old versions of the ORB, Java and JBoss are given and not a subject of change.

After a migration project (the application was originally deployed in separate J2EE application servers, but is now migrated to one application within the JBoss using partially Java EE 5 and one standalone Java application) we now have the situation that a CORBA request from within the JBoss leads to an `org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST` exception.

I verified the situation by writing a small test class doing the call in question and letting it run once from outside the JBoss via a standalone Java program and once from inside within an MBean via JBoss' JMX console. In the first case, everything works fine, in the second case I get the error.

I already stepped into some generated code and ORB code and found out that when the stub distinguishes between local and remote call, it finds a POA and goes for the local call, despite the fact that the opposite part of that request is in a separate JVM process.

Any ideas what could cause that and where I should take a deeper look or maybe able to configure something? Even a workaround would be fine (like avoiding the local call), since those calls are not critical performance wise.

Comment: @Arjan Tijms: After having you edited some of my posts, I understood that JEE is not an appropriate term and that it should be Java EE. But in this question, it would be wrong, since the application was indeed a J2EE 1.4 application.

Comment: Sure! ;) Typically when people explicitly mean J2EE as opposed to Java EE they say "J2EE 1.4" or "old J2EE" etc. Of course in that context it should remain J2EE.